# Pipe the render output via command line interface

Tags: rendering, command-line

How can I pipe the render output via command line interface? I mean normally we are rendering and saving the render output as a PNG image file with this command:

```
blender --background untitled.blend --render-output //test_ --render-format PNG --use-extension 1 --render-frame 1
```

But I want to pipe the output to a let's say `imagehandler` program like this:

```
blender --background untitled.blend --render-frame 1 | imagehandler
```

in reality, I'm aiming to create a command like this:

```
pqiv -c -i < blender --background untitled.blend --render-frame 1
```

[pqiv](https://github.com/phillipberndt/pqiv) is an image viewer, you can install it with `apt-get install pqiv`

It supports creating **fully transparent window** so this is why I'm trying to pipe the output to **pqiv**.

Eventually, my goal is displaying the rendered image on the screen **as soon as it's rendered**.

*P.S. A solution with either piping or redirecting the output OR displaying the image directly using a feature of Blender is acceptable.*

Comment: Would a solution that waits for blender to finish the render, then close it and launch pqiv, work? In a Unix shell it should be as easy as `blender <options> && pqiv -c -i //test/<render_name>.png`

Comment: @NicolaSap actually I want to stream the rendered outputs. File open/close process would slow down my program. I want to create a video like effect at the end of day. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not aware of any way of taking the bitmap information directly from blender without writing/reading to hard drive